# web part new version not always loading

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts

I ran into a problem, after installing a new version of the webpart with changes, it does not always load on the site. Through time the old and new are loaded.
I incremented the package versions.

A new one is installed in the App catalog without errors.
[image: new package version in App catalog]

The SiteContent has also been updated.
[image: new version in Site Contents]

Tell me what could be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: In the screenshot I could the Added to all sites is `No`. Can you just mark it yes and then try.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to make the solution file (SPKG) from same PC
this error comes when we make SPKG file from different pc fetching the SPFX project from GIT hub